# How to target only the clicked class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, copy, click, queryselector

I'm trying to create an experience when someone clicks on a text it's copied and then it's replaced with a random phrase.

When I use `document.querySelector(".clickMe")` it will only affect the first instance of .clickMe. I would like to change the text of any of the `p` tags with .clickMe that was clicked on, not any other. How do I do this?

```js
      function copy(that){
            var inp =document.createElement('input');
            document.body.appendChild(inp)
            inp.value =that.textContent
            inp.select();
            document.execCommand('copy',false);
            inp.remove();
        }

var randomStrings = [
            "Roger Roger!",
            "Copied Copycat!",
            "Got it!", 
            "It's on the clipboard!",
            "Instantly memorized!",
            "Go paste it somewhere!",
            "Photocopied!",
            "Score!",
            "Your receipt!",
            "Literally copied!",
            "Carbon copied!",
            "Great artists steal!",
            "Precisely rendered!",
            "Virtually cloned!",
            "You got the knock off!",
            "Copy parady!",
            "Text impersonator!",
            "Hurry go paste it!",
            "So unoriginal!",
            "You got it!"
        ];

        document.querySelector(".clickMe").addEventListener("click", function() {
              randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random()*randomStrings.length-1));
              newText = randomStrings[randomIndex];
              this.innerHTML = newText;
        });
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: OliveDrab;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: BurlyWood;
}
```

```html
<p class="clickMe" onclick="copy(this)">Text One</p>

<p class="clickMe" onclick="copy(this)">Text Two</p>

<p class="clickMe" onclick="copy(this)">Text Three</p>

<p class="clickMe" onclick="copy(this)">Text Four</p>

<p class="clickMe" onclick="copy(this)">Text Five</p>
```

Comment: Please don't post the code related to your question at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and make your question meaningless. Always post the code you are asking about right in your question and inside of a Stack Snippet (the `<>` button on the edit toolbar) as I've done for you.

Comment: Will do, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Either iterate over all such elements with `querySelectorAll` and add a listener to each element, or use event delegation. Don't mix inline handlers and `addEventListener` - preferably, don't use inline handlers at all:

```js
for (const p of document.querySelectorAll('.clickMe')) {
  p.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random() * randomStrings.length - 1));
    const newText = randomStrings[randomIndex];
    p.innerHTML = newText;
    copy(p);
  });
}

function copy(that) {
  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.value = that.textContent
  inp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy', false);
  inp.remove();
}

var randomStrings = [
  "Roger Roger!",
  "Copied Copycat!",
  "Got it!",
  "It's on the clipboard!",
  "Instantly memorized!",
  "Go paste it somewhere!",
  "Photocopied!",
  "Score!",
  "Your receipt!",
  "Literally copied!",
  "Carbon copied!",
  "Great artists steal!",
  "Precisely rendered!",
  "Virtually cloned!",
  "You got the knock off!",
  "Copy parady!",
  "Text impersonator!",
  "Hurry go paste it!",
  "So unoriginal!",
  "You got it!"
];
```

```html
<p class="clickMe">Text One</p>

<p class="clickMe">Text Two</p>

<p class="clickMe">Text Three</p>

<p class="clickMe">Text Four</p>

<p class="clickMe">Text Five</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That makes sense. I didn't understand how to iterate all the elements with ```querySelectorAll.``` The copy part is off though, I want the original text copied before it's replaced with the random phrase.